# Why does VSIMEM have a path?

Tags: gdal

I'm struggling to understand VSIMEM. We're saving it in memory, similar to a "MEM" or "Memory" dataset, but it has a path under vsimem. If we're saving it to a path, then how is it in memory?

I've read the documentation as well as searched around, but am struggling to understand the concept. It also seems to introduce "Unlinking" after we're done, whereas with "MEM" or "Memory" datasets, it would operate like Shapefiles/TIFF datasets and we would just set it to None after we're done with it. Is Unlinking the equivalent of setting to None?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDAL [virtual filesystems](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html) have a path so you can refer to them just like you would a regular file on disk.  They're distinguished by the `/vsi*/` prefix.  This allows you to access less standard types of files, such as in-memory files, compressed files (.zip, .gz, .tar, .tar.gz archives), encrypted files, files stored on the network without modifying your code much if at all.

For `/vsimem`, the path doesn't exist on a local filesystem, it is in memory.  A ["MEM"](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mem.html) dataset is a specific format, whereas you can write *any* format (e.g. GeoTIFF, VRT, etc) that supports VirtualIO (listed in the formats [doc](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#driver-capabilities)) to `/vsimem`.

Setting a vsimem dataset handle to None won't delete the in memory "file", it will just delete the dataset handle. You can then re-open it if you want (e.g. `ds = gdal.OpenEx('/vsimem/some_geo.tif'); del ds; ds = gdal.OpenEx(etc...)`), though it will get cleaned up and memory reclaimed once the process that is accessing it completes (i.e. your python script finishes or you shut down your jupyter kernel)

Comment: Thanks! This made it make sense to me. Would you then say that the decision to use MEM versus the virtual /vsimem comes from if I want persistent reference through a path and support for different file formats? Is there any advantage to ever using MEM if VirtualIO is supported seeing as I can just unlink and free up the memory so it functions the same as MEM when I want it to?

Comment: No advantage for general use cases. MEM is a very limited format.  The only real advantage is that a MEM dataset can be created around an existing array in memory without having to write that array to a vsimem "file" and doubling up